# N queens algorithm in Python error

Tags: python

I am new to Python so I am just trying to build all the programs I have already built in C++ and Java just to get familiar with the syntax. I encountered errors in N queen problem which executed perfectly in C++ and Java.

Here is the code

```
def place(m , i):
    for j in range(0 , m - 1 ):
        if(x[j] == i or abs(x[j] - i) == abs(j-m)):
            return False
    return True

def nqueen(k , n ):
    for c in range(0, n):
        if( place(k , c) ):
            x[k] = c 
            if ( k == n):
                print(x)
            else:
                nqueen(k + 1 , n)

x = []
num = int(input("Enter the no. of rows and columns: "))
nqueen(0 , num)
```

The output for num = 4 would have been:

- 2 4 1 3
- 3 1 4 2

Errors encountered were :

- Traceback (most recent call last):
- File "D:\P\NQueen.py", line 18, in 
     nqueen(0 , num)
- File "D:\P\NQueen.py", line 10, in nqueen
     x[k] = c IndexError: list assignment index out of range

Please help me.

Comment: You need to initialize your array - something like `x = [0] * n` ...

Comment: @CorleyBrigman He initializes the array right above the input call. I am confused that it's not in a main function but maybe this is being called in the command line.

Comment: He initializes it with length 0, and then tries to access elements. Python doesn't let you do this - added an answer for it.

Answer (score 0):

range(0, n) produces a list starting at zero that goes up to n-1. Your check k==n needs to be k == (n-1). Otherwise you're calling x[n] which is one greater than you want. As an aside, the range function starts at 0 by default. You can just use range(m-1) and range(n) for the same results as you have currently.

Answer (score 0):

Python won't let you access an element unless you have already allocated it. It will let you grow it dynamically using `append`/`extend`, but to access a specific element, you must actually create the space:

```
In [1]: x = []
In [2]: x[0]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-1ae75c28907a> in <module>()
----> 1 x[0]    
IndexError: list index out of range
In [3]: x[0] = 1
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-1a754504edbf> in <module>()
----> 1 x[0] = 1    
IndexError: list assignment index out of range
In [4]: x = [0] * 4   
In [5]: x[0]
Out[5]: 0 (0x0)
In [6]: x[0] = 1
```

(note that you should also do this in C, but sometimes C will let you get away with unsafely, not sure about why Java would let you do this).

Other options for this are to iterate using append:

```
x = []
for entry in some_list:
     x.append(processed_value(entry))
```

Or to use a dictionary, which has other downsides, but also can be used as a sparse array. If you want default read functionality, you can use defaultdict:

```
In [8]: d1 = {}    
In [9]: d1[0] = 1    
In [10]: d2 = {}
In [11]: d2[0]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-8d722d66aade> in <module>()
----> 1 d2[0]
KeyError: 0
In [12]: from collections import defaultdict
In [13]: d2 = defaultdict(int)
In [14]: d2[0]
Out[14]: 0 (0x0)
```

Answer (score 0):

To initialise fixed length lists in python, you have to use something like

`x = [None] * num`  or  `x = [0] * num`

Also, `range(0,n)` iterates from `0 to n-1` inclusive, so in the `place` function, you should use `for j in range(0 , m )`

Apart from this, logic wise you should check for `if ( k == n-1)` instead of `if ( k == n)` before printing the result list